# How can I increase the size of a baseball cap?

Tags: clothing, comfort

My mom recently bought a baseball cap for me but the problem is that it fits my head, but it's a little too tight. I think that if I keep on using the cap, it will eventually expand.

Does anybody know how to stretch the cap without me having to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to put something like a soccer ball or basket ball inside the cap.  Let the air out of the ball, pull the brim of the cap over the ball then inflate it again to put a constant pressure on the brim to stretch it a little.

Comment: Also spray a bit of water on it before attempting to stretch it, and let it dry inn the stretched state.